# Convert Col2:ncol(df) to percent format

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that will have a new columnn appear every month. How do I convert all columns from Col2 to the number of columns in the dataframe to a percent format with no decimal points?

I think I should do something like this:

df

```
Col1    Col2   Col3
   A     0.3    0.4
   B     0.3    0.5
   C     0.3    0.1

df[,2:ncol(df)] <- label_percent(accuracy = 1L)(df[,2:ncol(df)])
```

But this doesn't work.

UPDATE: In databricks, I would like to sort from the display() function but it is not letting me because it is reading the label_percent() as a character value
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option will be `lapply` to loop over the columns, apply the `label_percent` and assign it back to the dataset columns.  If we want to sort the column do it before applying the `label_percent` as the output columns are `character` class

```
library(scales)
dfnew <- df[do.call(order, df[-1]),]
dfnew[-1] <- lapply(dfnew[-1], function(x) label_percent(accuracy = 1)(x))
```

Or if we want to `pad` 0 at the beginning

```
library(stringr)
df[-1] <- lapply(df[-1], function(x)
       str_pad(label_percent(accuracy = 1)(x), width = 3, pad = '0'))
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
library(scales)
df1 <- dfnew %>%
    mutate(across(-1, ~ label_percent(accuracy = 1)(.)))
```

Or use `percent` from `formattable`

```
library(formattable)
df1 <- df %>%
        mutate(across(-1, ~ percent(.)))


df1
#  Col1   Col2   Col3
#1    A 30.00% 40.00%
#2    B 30.00% 50.00%
#3    C 30.00% 10.00%
```

checking the `sort`ing

```
df1 %>% 
   arrange(Col3)
#  Col1   Col2   Col3
#1    C 30.00% 10.00%
#2    A 30.00% 40.00%
#3    B 30.00% 50.00%


df1 %>% 
    arrange(desc(Col3))
#  Col1   Col2   Col3
#1    B 30.00% 50.00%
#2    A 30.00% 40.00%
#3    C 30.00% 10.00%
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(Col1 = c("A", "B", "C"), Col2 = c(0.3, 0.3, 0.3
), Col3 = c(0.4, 0.5, 0.1)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-3L))
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226160/discussion-on-answer-by-akrun-convert-col2ncoldf-to-percent-format).